# LogStash Conf | Drop Empty Lines

Tags: logstash, kibana, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

The contents of LogStash's `conf` file looks like this:

```java
input {
    beats {
        port => 5044
    }
    
    file {
        path => "/usr/share/logstash/iway_logs/*"       
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
        #ignore_older => 0
        codec => multiline {
         pattern => "^\[%{NOTSPACE:timestamp}\]"
         negate => true
         what => "previous"
         max_lines => 2500
        }
  }
}

filter {    
    
    grok {
        match => {  "message" => 
            ['(?m)\[%{NOTSPACE:timestamp}\]%{SPACE}%{WORD:level}%{SPACE}\(%{NOTSPACE:entity}\)%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:rawlog}'         
            ]
        }
    }
                    
    date {
      match => [ "timestamp", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"]
      target => "@timestamp"
    }
        
    grok {
        match => { "entity" =>          ['(?:W.%{GREEDYDATA:channel}:%{GREEDYDATA:inlet}:%{GREEDYDATA:listener}\.%{GREEDYDATA:workerid}|W.%{GREEDYDATA:channel}\.%{GREEDYDATA:workerid}|%{GREEDYDATA:channel}:%{GREEDYDATA:inlet}:%{GREEDYDATA:listener}\.%{GREEDYDATA:workerid}|%{GREEDYDATA:channel}:%{GREEDYDATA:inlet}:%{GREEDYDATA:listener}|%{GREEDYDATA:channel})']
        }
    }
    
    dissect {
        mapping => {
            "[log][file][path]" => "/usr/share/logstash/iway_logs/%{serverName}#%{configName}#%{?ignore}.log"
        }
    }
    
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "${ELASTICSEARCH_HOST_PORT}"
        index => "iway_"
        user => "${ELASTIC_USERNAME}"
        password => "${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}"
        ssl => true
        ssl_certificate_verification => false
        cacert => "/certs/ca.crt"
    }
}
```

As one can make out, the idea is to parse a custom log employing multiline extraction. The extraction does its job. The log occasionally contains an empty first line. So:

```
[2022-11-29T12:23:15.073] DEBUG (manager) Generic XPath iFL functions use full XPath 1.0 syntax
[2022-11-29T12:23:15.074] DEBUG (manager) XPath 1.0 iFL functions use iWay's full syntax implementation
```

which naturally is causing Kibana to report an empty line:

[image]

In an attempt to supress this line from being sent to ES, I added the following as a last filter item:

```java
if ![message] {
  drop { }
}
    
if [message] =~ /^\s*$/ {
  drop { }
}
```

The resulting JSON payload to ES:

```json
{
    "@timestamp": [
        "2022-12-09T14:09:35.616Z"
    ],
    "@version": [
        "1"
    ],
    "@version.keyword": [
        "1"
    ],
    "event.original": [
        "\r"
    ],
    "event.original.keyword": [
        "\r"
    ],
    "host.name": [
        "xxx"
    ],
    "host.name.keyword": [
        "xxx"
    ],
    "log.file.path": [
        "/usr/share/logstash/iway_logs/localhost#iCLP#iway_2022-11-29T12_23_33.log"
    ],
    "log.file.path.keyword": [
        "/usr/share/logstash/iway_logs/localhost#iCLP#iway_2022-11-29T12_23_33.log"
    ],
    "message": [
        "\r"
    ],
    "message.keyword": [
        "\r"
    ],
    "tags": [
        "_grokparsefailure"
    ],
    "tags.keyword": [
        "_grokparsefailure"
    ],
    "_id": "oRc494QBirnaojU7W0Uf",
    "_index": "iway_",
    "_score": null
}
```

While this does drop the empty first line, it also unfortunately interferes with the multiline operation on other lines. In other words, the multiline operation does not work anymore. What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score -1):

Use of the following variation resolved the issue:

```js
if [message] =~ /\A\s*\Z/ {
  drop { }
}
```

This solution is based on [Badger](https://discuss.elastic.co/u/Badger)'s answer provided [on the Logstash forums](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/logstash-conf-drop-empty-lines/321674/4?u=srii), where this question was raised as well.

Comment: I flagged this for [deletion](/help/deleted-answers) because it consists almost entirely of a link. A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is [useful without it](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259): add context around the link so others will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part in case the linked page is unavailable. If you [edit] this answer to add more once it is deleted, please flag it for moderator attention so that it can be un-deleted.